# Kotlin float/int indirect comparison

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting, floating-point

For a project I am trying to implement a `Bit` class, that does all the usual stuff a bit should do.

The constructor should be able to take any `Number` and set the `Bit`'s internal state to `0` if the given value is `0`, else set it to `1`.

All works for integer inputs but when I get to float... apparently `0.0` is not equal to `0`.

```
class Bit(value: Number) {
    var value: Int = (value != 0).toInt() // I implemented Bool-to-Int myself
}
```

Now the problem:

```
println(Bit(0).value)   // Prints 0
println(Bit(0f).value)  // Prints 1
```

I thought this was some kind of approximation error, but when I tried `print(0f != 0)` I got `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'Float' and 'Int'`. However it had no issue comparing the numbers trough the constructor.

I feel there is some hidden type-casting magic I'm not aware of here so my question is basically "why is this not behaving as intended and what would be an elegant way to make it behave as intended?"

Comment: what kotlin version are you using? I can't even compile your sample (error on `.toInt()` cast).

Comment: @Pawel oh, sorry! I implemented the `toInt()` for booleans myself as a simple `if (someBool) 1 else 0`, I also edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you *exactly* why it's not behaving as you expect, but I can give you an easy fix!

The `Number` interface isn't as powerful as you might like, but the main thing it *does* give you is a way to convert its value to any of the standard numeric types.  You can use that like this:

```
class Bit(value: Number) {
    var value = if (value.toDouble() == 0.0) 0 else 1
}
```

This will work for all `Number` implementations: `Byte`, `Double`, `Float`, `Int`, `Long`, `Short`, `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, `BigDecimal`, `Striped64`, and any others you write or import.

(Whatever you do, I suggest you also override `value`'s setter, to make sure that it only ever holds 0 or 1.)

Comment: I tried that however something like `-0.5f` when passed trough `.toInt()` gives `0`, creating the `Bit` as `0`, when `-0.5` should not produce a `0` bit. In short, it truncates. (And thanks for the tip, the class is in reality quite large and completely unit tested and already has the setter ^^)

Comment: Whoops!  But I've now edited it to fix that, by converting to a double instead of an int.  That seems to work for all the integer and non-integer values I tried.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with value representation being boxed as stated in [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#representation).

As you've noticed you're not able to compare different types (when `Float` and `Int` are being represented natively). But you're not doing that, instead you use a `Number` type.

Consider following example:

```
println(0.0f == 0)  // error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Float' and 'Int'
val n : Number = 0L  // this forces value to be boxed
println(n == 0)   // compiles and prints false
```

At first compiler warns you that it's not possible to perform comparison. However if you box numerical value with an object then it is possible to use `equalsTo` operator as you have.

You will find that it returns `true` if and only if both sides are of the same type and same value.

Don't want to rain on your parade, but correct way of implementing your class is declaring separate constructors for each number type. That will prevent compiler from boxing your values and let you properly determine equality:

```
class Bit constructor(value : Boolean) {
    val value = if(value) 1 else 0

    constructor(value : Int) : this(value == 0)
    constructor(value : Float) : this(value == 0f)
    constructor(value : Long) : this(value == 0L)
    // etc
}
```